# Access threads from each other

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda

How can I write two threads which both interrupt each other, depending on which one finishes first? Here is a minimum working example of what I'm trying to do, but I get the error: `variable y might not have been initialized`, referring to `y.interrupt()`.

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread x;
    Thread y;
    x = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        // Wait for a second
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        y.interrupt();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("X interrupted");
      }
    });

    y = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        // Do something time-consuming, may take over a second
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        x.interrupt();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Y interrupted");
      }
    });
    x.start();
    y.start();
  }
}
```

A solution I have found is to replace x and y with two elements of an array, but this seems ugly and hacky. Is there a nicer solution?

Comment: Simply change `Thread y;` to `Thread y = null;`. That's it. Then first test for null before interrupting

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that changes the error to `local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`

Comment: Then make them static fields.  Please look this up since this is basic Java.

Comment: I don't know the memory model detail of Java, but I would hazard a guess that you need a read/load memory barrier before `x.start();`. `volatile` keyword sometimes provides such semantics